# How can i group by and count on three columns and transfer the results in one data frame

Tags: python

I have a data frame as such:

```
+------+------------+------+------------+------+------------+
| var1 | var1_total | var2 | var2_total | var3 | var3_total |
+------+------------+------+------------+------+------------+
|    1 |         10 |    5 |         40 |    3 |         20 |
|    4 |        200 |    3 |        125 |    1 |        450 |
|    5 |         22 |    3 |        320 |    3 |        250 |
|    1 |         45 |    2 |         50 |    5 |        150 |
+------+------------+------+------------+------+------------+
```

I would like to count the number of occurrences per group and transfer the result in one single data frame. Right now i'm transferring all the results in separate data frame to then merge the end result which is I believe contain unnecessary steps
so my code is:

```
df2= df1.groupby('var1')['var1_total'].count()
df3= df1.groupby('var2')['var2_total'].count()
df4= df1.groupby('var3')['var3_total'].count()
```

The final output should look like - except the '#' should be the counts per bins:

```
+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| code | var1_counts | var2_counts | var3_counts |
+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|    1 | #           | #           | #           |
|    2 | #           | #           | #           |
|    3 | #           | #           | #           |
|    4 | #           | #           | #           |
|    5 | #           | #           | #           |
+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check with `melt`

```
df[['var1','var2','var3']].melt().groupby(['variable','value']).size().unstack(level=0,fill_value=0)
Out[476]: 
variable  var1  var2  var3
value                     
1            2     0     1
2            0     1     0
3            0     2     2
4            1     0     0
5            1     1     1
```